# Optimizing jQuery plugin to truncate text based on size of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I am not the most savey at javascript or jQuery but I know them well enough.  I put together a quick plugin I can drop into any of my websites that will truncate the text of a container dynamically without actually removing the text.

So if I have a container 600x600 pixels, I want the text to fit nicely in there, and when it needs to be cut off, add ... after the last word.

I couldn't find anything that really did this, so I created the following plugin.

It works, it works really great, the only problem is it is painfully slow.  Simply because if goes through each line of text.

Is there a way to optimize this at all and not loose the functionality?

```
// To work the parent div to class .jFit must have it's height defined.
// Stylized spans may cause problems.

$(function() {
    $('.jFit').each(function() {
        $(this).jFit();
    });
});

var resizeTimer;
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.jFit').each(function() {
            $(this).jFit(true);
        });
    }, 150);
});


jQuery.fn.jFit = function(resize = false) {
    var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height(),
        maxHeight = parentHeight,
        height = 0,
        char = 0,
        i = 1,
        str = '',
        last = 0;

    $(this).siblings().each(function() {
        maxHeight -= $(this).outerHeight();
        maxHeight -= parseInt($(this).css('margin-top'));
        maxHeight -= parseInt($(this).css('margin-bottom'));
    });

    if (resize) {
        $(this).find('.jFit-ellipsis').remove();
        var span = $(this).find('.jFit-hide'),
            contents = span.html();
        span.remove();
        $(this).append(contents);
    }

    while ((str = $(this).line(i))['text'] != "") {
        height += str['lineHeight'];
        if (maxHeight > height) {
            char += str['text'].length;
            last = str['text'].length - $.trim(str['text']).lastIndexOf(' ');
            i++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($.trim(str['text']).lastIndexOf(' ')<0) {
        char -= str['text'].length;
        str['text'] = $(this).line(i-1 | 0)['text'];

        if (str['text'].match('<br\s*\/?>$')) {
            char -= str['text'].length;
            char += str['text'].lastIndexOf('<');
        }
        last = 0;
    }

    if (str['text'].match('/(.|,|;|:)$/')) {
        last += 1;
    }

    if (str['text']!='') {
        $(this).html($(this).html().substring(0,char-(last))+'<span class="jFit-ellipsis">...</span><span class="jFit-hide" style="display: none;">'+$(this).html().substring(char-(last)));
        $(this).append('</span>');
    }
}

jQuery.fn.line = function(line) {
    var dummy = this.clone().css({
        top: -9999,
        left: -9999,
        position: 'absolute',
        width: this.width()
    }).appendTo(this.parent());
    var text = dummy.html().match(/(<.*?span[^>]*>|<br.*?>|[\w\.\,]+[\s\.\,])/g);

    var words = text.length,
        lastTopOffset = 0,
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 0,
        ret = '',
        found = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < words; ++i) {
        dummy.html(
            text.slice(0,i).join('') +
            text[i].replace(/(\S)/, '$1<span id="jFit-lh" style="line-height:inherit;"/>') +
            text.slice(i+1).join('')
        );

        var topOffset = jQuery('#jFit-lh', dummy).offset().top;
        lineHeight = $('#jFit-lh').height();
        if (topOffset !== lastTopOffset) {
            lineNumber += 1;
        }
        lastTopOffset = topOffset;

        if (lineNumber === line) {
            found = true;
            ret += text[i];
        } else {
            if (found) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    dummy.remove();
    return {text:ret,lineHeight:lineHeight};
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you found this, but there is http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/ which seems to do what you want

Comment: @JosephYoung it does work quite a bit faster however, it does not like breaks.  Anytime there is a break it adds the ... after the line break, which is not correct

Comment: Is there a specific reason you decided not to use css `text-overflow:ellipsis`?

Comment: @Dekel `text-overflow: ellipsis` doesn't work on multiple lines

Comment: [Check this out](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/).